# how to get odata.nextlink from the returned json object in java and call the odata.nextlink url

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Currently I'm using

```
 HttpSession session = (HttpSession) request.getSession();
        AuthenticationResult result = (AuthenticationResult) session.getAttribute(AuthHelper.PRINCIPAL_SESSION_NAME);
        String accessToken = result.getAccessToken();
        String tenant = session.getServletContext().getInitParameter("tenant");
        url = new URL("https://graph.windows.net/" + tenant + "/users/" + result.getUserInfo().getUniqueId()
                + "/memberOf?api-version=1.6");

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Set the appropriate header fields in the request header.
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("api-version", "1.6");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata");


    jsonResponse = HttpClientHelper.getResponseStringFromConn(con, true);
```

which returns the groups which the user belongs to. It is limited to 100 and I'm getting the odata.nextlink. I currently don't know how to use that and recall the graph api to fetch the next set of 100

Please help!!
Or is there any way to increase the limit of response to be greater than 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the odata.nextlink would show like : ***directoryObjects/$/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User/b202e3e2-ead2-4878-8f77-81889ce30989/memberOf?$skiptoken=X'445370740900010000000000000000140000005948A9EA0D7571449DAAEF76844271C101000000000000000000000000000017312E322E3834302E3131333535362E312E342E32333331020000000000018020591539727941B538A64692E459E9'***

Then, you just need to generate a new request url as: ***new URL("https://graph.windows.net/" + tenant + "/" +odata.netlink + "&api-version=1.6");***

Then, just make another request with Authorization header.

Thanks.